# Black screen after boot

Tags: raspbian, boot

I'm running the latest version of Raspbian on my Raspberry Pi 2 (Model B) and so far it's been working just fine. However, it just won't show anything on screen when it's done booting.

It does display stuff during the boot, but after that I'm getting a black screen. Tried turning it off and on again and checking the SD card for errors to no avail.

Does anybody here know what to do?

Comment: I might sound stupid but I have been caught out by the fact the screen saver can cut in very quickly and if you have no keyboard /mouse input the screen stays black. Press a key or move the mouse then try switching to the console ALT+F1

Comment: Holy crap, that was it. So simple.

Comment: @rob what to do after you reach the console?

Comment: ALT+F1 gets us to the console after the "blank screen" issue, but what do we do after that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Watch out for the screen saver. If you do not have a keyboard or mouse plugged in the screen will go black thinking there is no input.

Plugin a keyboard/mouse and press a key or give it a wiggle.

If you are running a kiosk type setup you can disable the the screen blanking with

```
xset s off 
xset -dpms 
xset s noblank
```